# USB 2.0 cable to USB C output

Tags: usb, wiring, usb-device, usb-c

I've got a Streamdeck that has a USB 2.0 out as a fixed cable. I've bought a USB C 2.0 board that I want to wire up so I don't have a fixed cable anymore.

My issue is I don't know what the two black cables are, as I assumed red is for power, white is for D-, green is for D+ and black is ground. That's as much as I know when it comes to this sort of stuff and I don't know what the last black cable is for. I've read it's something to do with OTG or something, but how would I then wire that up or would I not need to? Should I just wire it to ground?

Thanks in advance.

---

USB C 2.0 Breakout Board that I have.
[image: Image of the USB C 2.0 Breakout Board that I have.]

Streamdeck PCB USB wiring (USB 2.0)
[image: Image of the Streamdeck PCB USB wiring (USB 2.0)]

Comment: This type of modification is generally not a good idea.  If you are going to do it, then *you* need to read the documentation, and not just post a picture of some random item you bought from a dubious source.

Comment: Both blacks are ground. One is the sheild.

Comment: Yes, in-fact you can see one black is thicker than the other wires, that one is the shield braid covered  by some heat-shrink.

Answer (score 1):

As Tom said, both black wires are grounds. You should be more concerned about correctness of auxiliary pins on the Type-C receptacle, CC1 and CC2 in particular, otherwise it won't work.

Fortunately, the breakout board does already have proper pull-downs, and a proper cross between D+ and D- wires.

[image]

So, you are lucky, and your rework should work. I am not sure although if you will be satisfied with thick, stiff, and expensive Type-C cable, which won't hold in the receptacle and fall off under nearly every movement of your device.

Comment: USB-C is pretty good, so long as you keep lint (and other crud) out of It. I measured 800 gramme-force pull force on my laptop USB jack.  my phone jack once filled with pocket lint I cleared that using using a plastic spike.  USB2 to USB-C cables are not fat because they only need the USB2 conductors.  USB3 to USB-C are fat like all USB3 cables are.